# Issue with AWS when migrate Joomla site

Tags: php, joomla, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, joomla3.0

I have a site Joomla run in a not.
Now I want migrate it into AWS of Amazon.
I used Akeba Backup to backup and restore it in AWS.
But I recevied a blank page (both Frontend and Backend)
When I enable show error in configuration file, I received a message:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/libraries/joomla/cache/storage/memcache.php on line 124".
I tried some solution, but not success.

P/s: I tried install a new Joomla in AWS, I received same problem.

Thank you so much and have a nice day.

Comment: What solution did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the issue mentioned here...

https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/site-restoration/11941-kickstart-restore-appears-to-work-fine-but-site-generates-500-error.html

To quote what what may be the solution from that page...

> Your old site was using memcache as the cache storage
>   handler, but the new site doesn't support it. No problem, we will
>   revert to the good ol' file storage handler. Open your
>   configuration.php file with a text editor and find the line which
>   begins with
>
> public $cache_handler
>
> and change it to read
>
> public $cache_handler = 'file';
>
> Save that file (and make sure it's uploaded to your site's root), then
>   reload the site. It should now load correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Now I can access administrator but have poblem with frontend.
I used falang for multi language and sh404sef for seo.
But now when I access frontend.
When I tried disable sh404sef I can access homepage, but when I try go to a article, I received a error
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /var/www/html/components/com_k2/helpers/route.php on line 93"

Comment: There's a good troubleshooting guide here, which is worth a read through to see if anything applies: https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/troubleshooter/prbasicts.html - not sure beyond that, I'm afraid.